# Loading, Resizing and Moving object imported from COLLADA (*.dae) file in Sketchup Ruby API

Tags: ruby, sketchup

I created DaeImporter class (it inherited from Importer interface) for importing *.dae file. And in load_file function of importer class. I got the path of the file i have imported

But i need to open it and display the 3D image  , resize it and place it at given position, and this function have to implement in DaeImporter class.

I see with image objects, Entities class have method add_image for add image into entites, resize and place it at given postion. Does Entites class have same method used for dae file. If it did not have, what could i do for this situation.

Thanks for helping me !

Comment: Why are you implementing the Importer class for what appear to be DAE when you expect SketchUp to to load the format? The IMporter class is for adding Importers that SketchUp doesn't support out of the box.

Comment: I assume by "3D Image" you mean "3D model"? An "Image" is a 2D element.

Comment: Yes, i mean "3D Image" for "3D model" and "Image" is a 2D element. Sorry.
My requirement is when user import dae file( exactly user import 2D element in dae file),it will automatically resize with a given size, and automatically move to given position. 
So i think i have to create custom importer class , because it inherited from Importer interface, and it have callback function load_file (it is call automatically when user import file). I will process reading file,resizing and moving 2D element in this function. Is this a true way? Do you have alternative method?

Comment: If you implement the `Importer` class you are responsible for reading, decoding and generating the SketchUp entities. So what I think you really are looking for is being notified when the user imports an DAE file? There is no notification for importer actions, you can listen for when new components or entities are added, but there is no way of knowing they come from an DAE import.

Comment: Yes, i understood. Thanks for your guide, i found how to listen for when new components or entities are added, and how to move it

Answer (score 0):

If you want to import a file that isn't SKP, then use `Model.import`: http://www.sketchup.com/intl/en/developer/docs/ourdoc/model.php#import

The `Importer` class is for adding extra formats that SketchUp doesn't support out of the box.

Comment: I used Model.import to import Dae file, but i had 2 problems:
1) Parameter in Model.import function is the path of the file, but this path is obtained when user select a file in model import dialog
2) i  don't know how to resize and move it. I read in API, and i use group to move one element to given position. But i have to new entity in group, and i don't know what i have to add in new entites ,before moving this group. 
http://www.sketchup.com/intl/en/developer/docs/ourdoc/group.php#move

Comment: 1. Why is this a problem? You need to be more specifies to what you have tried that gives errors and what your overall concept you are trying to solve.

Comment: 2. This another question again. Please post that as a new post. Also please check the user guidelines for this site, as if you keep bundling questions like this the moderator will close them down.

Comment: Sorry for my mistake, please sympathize for me

Comment: No worries - keep asking, but stick with the guidelines. This site isn't a forum.